# np.flatten() is returning all zeros?

Tags: python, numpy, opencv

I have an RGB image which I want to convert into grayscale, and flatten the image into a vector. So I wrote the following code :

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

path="F:\TestProject\DatasetFINAL\Subject01\A_01_+10.Jpg"
img=cv2.imread(path)
imgGray=cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_RGB2GRAY)
flatImg=imgGray.flatten()
```

But when I write `print(flatImg)` I get :
`[0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]`
Am I missing something? I also used `ravel()` but still I get the same issue. This should have been quite straightforward.
Please help.

Edit :

Here is the image:
[image: Here is the image]

The reason I didn't include it earlier is that when I printed `imgGray` the values weren't all zero.

Comment: Please share the image you are trying to read. No one can properly help if you just share an image path. Thanks.

Comment: Your code works for me on a random screenshot. Check the image you are opening and the path. The '.Jpg' and the name seems strange.

Comment: Tested with your image. There are a lot of 0 in the image; and the print is not displaying the entire (307200,) values; but there are not all 0. You think you have a problem when really you don't. Try np.where(flatImg !=0) and you'll see that it returns a non empty array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your code is fully working. Try to check if the path to your image is correct.
Also, instead of converting RGB image to grayscale image you can read an image in grayscale mode:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
path="F:\TestProject\DatasetFINAL\Subject01\A_01_+10.Jpg"
imgGray=cv2.imread(path,cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
flatImg=imgGray.flatten()

print(flatImg)
```

Comment: Thanks.  checked the code with another image and I see it working. But any idea what happened with that specific image? The path is correct because I used the cv2.imshow() to display the image and it displayed fine.